# Different results in partial correlation with packages ppcor and correlation (method="spearman")

Tags: r, correlation, partial

I am running a partial correlation var1, var2 and var3 with pcor (package ppcor) and correlation (package correlation). Both with the spearman method but the results are different. Could someone tell me where my mistake is?
I Thank you I advance!!

```
var1 <- c(1.283e-04 ,1.284e-03 ,1.129e-04 ,1.698e-05, 1.853e-05 ,6.170e-05, 8.921e-06 ,2.880e-04,  3.526e-05 ,7.063e-05 ,4.152e-05, 3.580e-05 ,5.995e-04 ,7.177e-05 ,1.201e-04 ,8.308e-04, 9.538e-05, 1.269e-04 ,2.282e-05 ,3.311e-05 ,9.737e-05 ,3.116e-05)
var2 <- c(104.69974 ,82.73531,  80.11138,  93.30909,  63.92139 ,106.68449,  67.84821, 105.61487,  74.03226, 113.31995 , 26.73993,16.89038  ,90.67514 , 87.42241 , 67.88991, 119.01793,  71.56187 , 96.25090 , 16.89373 ,100.48780 , 62.84884 ,100.26991)
var3 <- c(45.900783 ,107.176287,  28.082737 , 25.672727 , 22.274216,  37.254902 ,  6.922435 , 85.172005,  38.838710,  26.305221,97.649573 , 38.478747  ,53.042688  ,55.962104 , 22.763761  ,48.713952,  28.194726,  40.555155,  33.605813,  26.463415,21.860465 , 46.153846)

pcor(data.frame(var1=var1, var2=var2, var3=var3), method="spearman")
$estimate
          var1       var2       var3
var1 1.0000000 0.27801067 0.48177768
var2 0.2780107 1.00000000 0.09467777
var3 0.4817777 0.09467777 1.00000000

$p.value
           var1      var2       var3
var1 0.00000000 0.2223786 0.02700195
var2 0.22237855 0.0000000 0.68311211
var3 0.02700195 0.6831121 0.00000000

$statistic
         var1     var2     var3
var1 0.000000 1.261553 2.396480
var2 1.261553 0.000000 0.414553
var3 2.396480 0.414553 0.000000

$n
[1] 22

$gp
[1] 1

$method
[1] "spearman"

data.frame(var1=var1, var2=var2, var3=var3) %>% correlation(partial=T, method="spearman", p_adjust="none")

Parameter1 | Parameter2 |  rho |        95% CI |       S |     p
----------------------------------------------------------------
var1       |       var2 | 0.04 | [-0.40, 0.47] | 1698.00 | 0.855
var1       |       var3 | 0.42 | [-0.01, 0.72] | 1026.00 | 0.051
var2       |       var3 | 0.06 | [-0.38, 0.48] | 1666.00 | 0.793

p-value adjustment method: none
Observations: 22
```